# Database stucture for dynamic values

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am working on a new project and I could use some assistance in designing the database.

Imagine these tables:

```
table groups
---------------------
group_id


table supplements
---------------------
supp_id
supp_name
supp_price


table recipes
---------------------
rec_id
supp_id
supp_weight
```

So, let me explain.

The user  can add `groups` (of animals) to his account. He can also add (food)`supplements`. With two or more `supplements` he can create a `recipe`.

So far no problems.

Then the user must be able to register the food he gives his animals. So I will need a table `given_food` or something. Normally I would use the `rec_id` and add it to the table, combined with the `group_id` and `date`, **but**

- the user should be able to deviate from the `recipe`. Meaning that it is possible that he feeds 90% or 110% of the recipe.
- the price from supplements may deviate from week to week (or even day to day). We want to register the costs, so if the user *now* changes the price, it *should not* affect the already given recipes from the past.

So the question is, how do I save this info at best in a database?

Answer (score 1):

For the costs you should add a pricing table like

```
table prices
-----------
p_id
p_suppid
p_price
p_validfrom   -- date at which new price was given
```

and the group table should be equipped with an `amount` column:

```
table groups
------------
g_id
g_recid
g_amount  -- percentage of nominal amount (90 ... 110)
```

by joining these tables you should be able to organise all the data you want. The valid price for the 'supplement's  (or ingredients) at a particular date (currentdate) can be found by doing

```
SELECT supp_id, p_price FROM supplements 
INNER JOIN prices ON p_id=( SELECT p_id   -- finds id of the latest
                            FROM prices   -- pricing info before currentdate
                            WHERE p_suppid=supp_id 
                            AND p_validfrom < currentdate
                            ORDER BY p_validfrom DESC LIMIT 1 )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I understand what you are saying. But how would I save the given food to the database? The user should also be able to edit one supplement of the recipe. Not only a total.

Comment: Well, editing 'one supplement of the recipe' to me is the equivalent of a *new recipe* (albeit a variant of an existing one). So, in this case a new `rec_id` would be generated in table `recipe` and all the `supp_id` records of the previous recipe would be added with modified `supp_weight`s.